# MongoNetworkError : failed to connect to server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

First time working with mongoDb inside a Node.js app (using mLab) but i'm unable to connect.
Same exact code works just fine if i try to connect to mongoDB Atlas.

```
 // not working with mLab link and credentials
 mongoose.connect(mLabConnectionString)
 .then(success => console.log(success))
 .catch(error => console.log(error))

 // working with atlas link and credentials
 mongoose.connect(atlasConnectionString)
 .then(success => console.log(success))
 .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Followed these steps https://docs.mlab.com/troubleshooting-connection-issues/
and i do have network access, i'm using database user credentials to connect (not my mLab account credentials) and my password just contains chars and numbers. That's the error i'm getting :

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [***my_database***] 
on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ***my_database*** ***my_database***]
at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\akain\Desktop\devconnector\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:564:11)
at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\akain\Desktop\mongotest\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:317:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\akain\Desktop\mongotest\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:246:50)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
name: 'MongoNetworkError',
errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
[Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Now the weird part : If i try to connect to mLab using mongo shell, not only everything works (from the shell), but i'm also able to connect without problem from my app. As soon as i close the shell and restart the app i get the error again.

I've also tried using mongoDb Node client instead of mongoose getting the same exact behaviour.

Comment: Are you 100% your user credentials on mLab are correct? As in, you've added a user in the users tab? Does your Mongo URL have the correct port number too?

Comment: i'm using the same credentials to connect from the mongo shell and they work just fine, so i'm 100% sure on both, also by connecting fro  the shell first and restarting the app everything works, so i'm inclined to to think it can't be a credential/database user issue

Comment: Would we be able to see your connection string? Obviously blanking out the password :)

Comment: sure, there you go 'mongodb://testuser:mypass@ds121295.mlab.com:21295/testdatabase'